# Вопрос должен быть закрыт, но сообщество так не думает. Или все не так просто?

Tags: обсуждение

Увидел тут для себя немного [странный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1531917/220553), где автор спрашивает:

> где должен находиться лимит терпения, достигнув который не стыдно посмотреть ответ?

Вопрос имеет много голосов ЗА, также имеет два ответа, которые также имеют ЗА, всех вроде все устраивает, но есть одно НО, на SO подобные вопросы неуместны, ибо ответ у всех будет свой, у нас даже есть "закрывашка" специальная:

> **Невозможно дать объективный ответ**
> Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Вопрос посмотрели модераторы (один даже просит отметить верный ответ), и по истории видно, что некоторым он попался в очереди проверок, где нажали "Оставить открытым". Но почему?

Вот давайте взглянем на самый залайканый ответ:

> Быстрый ответ для Вашего случая - неделя.
> ...
> Вам самому надо потратить день, чтобы поставить цели и сроки. От этого может зависеть многое.

Почему неделя? Почему не день, два? Может месяц? То есть, мы можем подставить сюда любое значение, и ответ будет верным, ну а все это основывается "на мнениях", чего сообщество, на сколько я знаю, не очень желает видеть на сайте. Получается, если этот вопрос открыт, значит можно задавать вопросы по типу "Должен я идти в институт?", "Какой язык учить?", "Какая зарплата будет приемлемой для программиста?", ну и куча других, где все сводится к мнению конкретного человека, которое может не подойти другому, так?

Ребят, я не против самого вопроса, автора, и чего либо еще, просто диссонанс в голове при просмотре подобного. Я не пойму почему его не закрыли как все остальные подобные, почему этот норма, а другие нет? Может кто подскажет? Или ответ "для Вашего случая - неделя" - это хороший, каноничный ответ, подкреплен фактами, и др. существенной информацией? Ну вон сейчас там два ответа, какой из них верен? Не понятно...

Comment: В данном конкретном случае я просто принял решение не мешать сообществу. Это не меняет никаких правил, а скорее исключение. А так моё мнение совпадает с вашим.

Comment: @aepot Закрытие вопроса не мешает его комментировать, чем по сути и являются все те ответы. Как по мне, весьма странно отходить от правил лишь потому, что на вопросе много "лайков" или есть ответы, это даже губительно в некой мере, ибо в следующий раз автор задаст еще ряд таких вопросов, ибо будет думать, что это "норма". Тоже самое касается и всех остальных участников. Ну серьезно, сейчас почти каждый думают (особенно новички), что SO это форум, а подобным мы только утверждаем это мнение.

Comment: Объективно, новички ничего не знают о ранее заданных вопросах, потому что не ищут ничего. А кто ищет - редко спрашивает, потому что практически всё уже отвечено. Не на SO, так в других местах. Так что риск, о котором вы говорите, пренебрежительно мал. Худшее, что в происходящем можно найти это неоднозначность в реакциях сообщества и модераторов на сомнительный контент. Одно адски минусуют и закрывают, другое наоборот. Я бы сразу закрыл, если бы там был хоть один голос за закрытие от сообщества, но их не было. Так что успеем ещё закрыть.

Comment: В очереди проверок "Оставить открытым" это аудит. Так как вопрос заплюсовали, автоматика стала его подсовывать как хороший в аудитах очереди проверок. На деле его до вас никто и не пытался закрыть...

Comment: _Получается, если этот вопрос открыт, значит можно задавать вопросы где все сводится к мнению конкретного человека, которое может не подойти другому, так?_ - нет, не так. Вопрос уже закрыт

Comment: Не понимаю твоего возмущения. Вопрос не должен быть на SO ибо нельзя дать `каноничный ответ, подкреплен фактами, и др. существенной информацией`? Так на SO каждый второй ответ - чистая субъективщина и их принимают. Странно почему,  скорее всего, что автора он устроил. Эту же логику можна использовать и для  вопроса. Если много ЗА на вопросе, выходит что он интересует не только автора. На ответе тоже много положительних голосов от людей которых  устроил такой ответ. Так вот, учитывая вышесказаное, почему этот вопрос должен быть закрыт?

Comment: Логику на этом ресурсе давно не стОит искать)) У всех своё мнение. Так что остаётся самому действовать только по тому, что сам считаешь правильным.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Хм, я смотрел по истории ([например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/868894), там висит конкретный участник, думал он и оставил вопрос открытом. Если это система, то весьма странное решение, голоса зачастую не показатель.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру SO не форум, а сайт, где сообщество пытается собрать полезные **для всех** вопросы и ответы на них. Вот в чем польза "где должен находиться лимит терпения" для сообщества? Вот вы прочитали наверно этот вопрос и ответы, вам он был полезен? Скорей всего нет, ибо у каждого свои "лимиты". Также SO это про программирование, про языки программирования, про решение конкретных задач, но не про субъективное обсуждение выгорание человека. Поэтому, вопросы, на которые нельзя дать один верный ответ, на SO неуместны, их закрывают. Ну а то, что залайкали - я думаю с целью поддержать автора.

Comment: Надпись "Аудит пройден" выдает, что это фальшивая проверка, чтобы проверить внимательность проверяющих в очереди, и реального голоса за закрытие не было. Поскольку это всего лишь аудит, брать заплюсованный вопрос нормально. Его наличие никак не мешает другим участникам закрыть вопрос (что Grundy и продемонстрировал).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ полностью с тобой согласен.да это сайт для решения конкретных задач, но решают их люди, у которых свое мнение и видение конкретной задачи. На со нет таких вопросов, где ответ будет однозначен и не зависеть от взглядов отвечающего(вопрос где только один ответ верный), ибо обычно вопросы чуть сложнее чем дважды два. Да и если руководиться твоей логикой, то и на вопрос который тебе не понравился, можно ответить однозначно. К примеру "У каждого свои временные лимиты" вполне себе конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос :D

Comment: @ВадимАлександру первый раз слышу, что на SO нет вопросов, где ответ будет однозначным. Сам такие вопросы давал уйму раз, подробные, развернутые, охватывающие каждый аспект вопроса, чтоб сам ответ был полезен не только автору, но и всем будущим читателям. Если вопрос "2+2", то на него есть конкретный ответ, с конкретным решением, ну а если вопрос "как заставить себя писать код", то на него невозможно ответить, ибо один заставляет себя кнутом, другой пряником, а третий в баню ходит, то есть у каждого свое решение, и вопрос превращается в обсуждение, форум, что не формат SO.

Comment: @Dev18, однажды некто опубликовал политически ангажированный вопрос, небрежно замаскированный под технический, но по содержанию просто напросто оскорбляющий действующего главу одной из стран. И знаете, люди стали всерьёз обсуждать, соответствует или нет этот вопрос тематике сайта. А когда я написал нейтральный комментарий, который сводился к тому, что данный вопрос может оскорбить чьи-то чувства, один из экс-модераторов прямым текстом написал мне в публичном комментарии, что это про-европейская площадки, и таким как я тут не место. Что это было, до сих пор не понял :-)